# How do I use the chrome.sessions API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension that should restore the last session like this

```
if(request.msg == "reopen"){chrome.sessions.restore(null, null)}
```

but this doesn't work.

(See the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregard this, I forgot to set the 'sessions' permission in the manifest.